# R function for collapsing multiple ranges of different columns from wide to long format?

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape

I've a dataset with multiple different ranges of columns in each row (each row corresponds to one individual), as below. Each instance of the different column types have 3 levels (0,1 and 2).

```
id  col1_0 col1_1 col1_2  col2_0  col2_1 col2_2  col3_0 col3_1 col3_2
1       0      1      3       2       2      3       3      4      5
2       1      1      2       2       4      7       4      5      5
.
.
etc.
```

What I would need is to collapse all col1 into one column, all col2 into another and all col3's into another, for each id. As below.

```
id  x  col1 col2 col4
1   0     0    2    3       
1   1     1    2    4
1   2     3    3    5
2   0     1    2    4
2   1     1    4    5
2   2     1    7    5
.
.
etc.
```

In addition, I would also need to create an x-column with values 0,1 and 2, for each id. However, I only manage to collapse the first range of columns (col1) with the code below.

```
library(tidyverse)

longer_data <- dataframe %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  pivot_longer(col1_0:col1_2, names_to = "x1", values_to = "col1")
```

x1 here creates a column with the original column names. So I would create need an additional x-column that only keeps the last numbers of the original column names.

Is there a way to achieve this? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We don't need any `group_by`.  It can be directly done with `pivot_longer` by specifying the `names_sep` and the `.value` in `names_to`.  Note the order of `.value` and `x`.  It implies the values of that column should go into the each of those prefixes before the `_` and the new column with suffix stub goes into 'x'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = c('.value', 'x'), names_sep = "_")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#     id x      col1  col2  col3
#  <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1 0         0     2     3
#2     1 1         1     2     4
#3     1 2         3     3     5
#4     2 0         1     2     4
#5     2 1         1     4     5
#6     2 2         2     7     5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:2, col1_0 = 0:1, col1_1 = c(1L, 1L), col1_2 = 3:2, 
    col2_0 = c(2L, 2L), col2_1 = c(2L, 4L), col2_2 = c(3L, 7L
    ), col3_0 = 3:4, col3_1 = 4:5, col3_2 = c(5L, 5L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `reshape`, where `timevar="x"` creates a column named `x`, and `sep="_"` helps to fetch the last numbers of the original column names.

```
res <- reshape(
  df,
  direction = "long",
  idvar = "id",
  varying = -1,
  timevar = "x",
  sep = "_"
)
res <- res[order(res$id), ]
```

- Output

```
> res
    id x col1 col2 col3
1.0  1 0    0    2    3
1.1  1 1    1    2    4
1.2  1 2    3    3    5
2.0  2 0    1    2    4
2.1  2 1    1    4    5
2.2  2 2    2    7    5
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = 1:2, col1_0 = 0:1, col1_1 = c(1L, 1L), col1_2 = 3:2,
    col2_0 = c(2L, 2L), col2_1 = c(2L, 4L), col2_2 = c(3L, 7L
    ), col3_0 = 3:4, col3_1 = 4:5, col3_2 = c(5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```